# In Matthew 27, why does the Vulgate call the graves of people who were resurrected along with Jesus "monumentum", but Jesus's grave "sepulchrum"?

Tags: vocabulary, vulgata

In Matthew 27, why does the Vulgate call the graves of people who were resurrected along with Jesus "monumentum", but Jesus's grave "sepulchrum"?

Matthew 27:53 says, in Vulgate:

> Et exeuntes de **monumentis** post resurrectionem ejus, venerunt in sanctam civitatem, et apparuerunt multis.

In the New International Version:

> They came out of the **tombs** after Jesus’ resurrection and went into the holy city and appeared to many people.

However, Matthew 27:61 says, in Vulgate:

> Erant autem ibi Maria Magdalene, et altera Maria, sedentes contra **sepulchrum**.

In the New International Version:

> Mary Magdalene and the other Mary were sitting there opposite the **tomb**.

So, was there some difference between *monumentum* and *sepulchrum*?

Comment: Just to confuse things, the French and Spanish translations use "sépulcres" and "sepulcros" for Matthew 27:53.

Comment: @RayButterworth I suppose the translators to French and Spanish were translating a lot less literally than Jerome was.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two words in the Vulgate are very literal translations of the words in the Greek original, which has ἐκ τῶν μνημείων [*ek tōn mnēmeiōn*] in 27:53 and ἀπέναντι τοῦ τάφου [*apenanti tou tafou*] in 27:61. Since μνημεῖον [*mnēmeion*] is etymologically related to μνήμη [*mnēmē*, "memory"], it is translated *monumentum* ["tomb, memorial", from *moneo*], whereas τάφος [*tafos*] is etymologically related to θάπτω [*thaptō*, "to bury"] and is translated *sepulchrum* ["tomb, burial place", from *sepelio*].

Comment: Is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your answer, as I do not speak a word of Greek, and I am not even sure about the alphabet.

Comment: I've added transliterations and further explanations of the words.

Comment: @gmvh Is "tafos" really related to "thapto", or is it a folk etymology? I mean, how do you explain the change from "th" to "t".

Comment: In the aorist, there are form of θάπτω that have the stemp ταφ-, so it ought to be a real etymology.

Comment: @FlatAssembler That could honestly be a good question in its own right, but the short answer is, there's a rule in Ancient Greek called _Grassmann's Law_: if you have two H's too close to each other, the first one disappears. The underlying root here is thaph-, which appears as taph- before a vowel (first one disappears) but as thap- if it comes before a consonant that suppresses the second h (first one doesn't disappear). Compare also hekh- "have" which appears as ekh- before a vowel and hek- before a consonant.