# How do you say "monument" (as opposed to "grave") in Latin?

Tags: word-request

When I asked [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15909/in-matthew-27-why-does-the-vulgate-call-the-graves-of-people-who-were-resurrect), I learned that the Latin word "monumentum" did not mean "monument", but "grave". So, how would you say "monument" in Latin?

For example, Vukovar Water Tower is a monument to the Vukovar Massacre, but it is not anybody's grave. The mass grave is in Ovčara.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the correct takeaway from that question, though I can see how that mistake can be made. A *monumentum* can indeed mean "monument" in our sense. You can see this plainly spelled out, too, in the [dictionary](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmonumentum).

> I. **that which preserves the remembrance of any thing, a memorial, a monument; esp. of buildings, statues, galleries, tombs erected to perpetuate the remembrance of a person or thing**

The primary definition isn't a grave, but rather some sort of marker for remembering someone or something, including a massacre.

It can also be used more metaphorically, such as when Horace says "[he has] created a *monument* more lasting the bronze" (*exegi monumentum aere perennius*, *Odes* 3.30.1). He is talking about poetry, not a tomb here.

While it can often mean a tomb, it's certainly not restricted to only that one definition.

Comment: There is a famous inscription in St Paul's Cathedral in London which says, *Lector, si monumentum requiris, circumspice*. It is a play on the double meaning of *monumentum*. The tomb is Christopher Wren's, who lies below the inscription. The monument too is Wren's, which is all around you; it is the cathedral which he designed.